# Create an extra entry box if user selects "Other" in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I want the user to be able to select an option ('Other') from a dropdown box and then have an entry box appear one column over. I want this function to work for 30 other dropdowns.

```
    self.ea_tf = StringVar()
    self.ea_tf.set(fixtures[0])
    self.e33 = OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.ea_tf, *fixtures, command=self.other_entry(15, "e33", "ea_tf"))
    self.e33.grid(row=15, column=5, stick=E+W)
```

Here is the function, 'other_entry':

```
     def other_entry(self, selection, row, el, var):
     if selection == "Other":
         self.var = StringVar()
         self.el = Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=self.var)
         self.el.grid(row=row, column=6)
```

It comes up with the error: "app instance has no attribute 'selection'". With other functions, it automatically gives the argument 'selection'. How do I make the selection one of the arguments?

Comment: Do i need to use lambda somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect indentions in your example.

```
    def other_entry(self, selection, row, el, var):
        if selection == "Other":
            self.var = StringVar()
            self.el = Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=self.var)
            self.el.grid(row=row, column=6)
```

---

Beside: `command` expects only function name without `()`

```
OptionMenu(..., command=onSelectionChange )

def onSelectionChange(self, selection):
    print selection
```

Using `command=self.other_entry(15, "e33", "ea_tf")` you run `other_entry(...)` and result is assigned to `command` as function name. Your `other_entry()` has no `return` so it returns `None` (as default) so you have `command=None`.

Most widget send only one agument to function assigned to `command`. if you want to send more arguments you need `lambda`

---

So probably you need `lambda` function

```
OptionMenu(..., command=lambda selection:self.other_entry(selection, 15, "e33", "ea_tf"))

def other_entry(self, selection, row, el, var):
    print selection, row, el, var
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I didn't know that selection could work like that.